# r : calculate time interval to reference

Tags: r, time

I would like to ask your help.

```
tibble::tribble(
        ~Last.TP,  ~D.EndStudy,    ~EOTvisit,       ~D.END,        ~D.IP,
        "2021-02-08", "2020-08-13", "2020-08-13", "2020-08-13", "2019-07-24",
        "2021-04-19", "2021-04-26", "2021-04-26", "2021-04-26", "2020-04-06",
        "2022-01-24", "2022-02-10", "2022-02-10", "2022-02-10", "2021-01-11"
  )
```

Desired temporary output is below tibble.
In below tibble,
Days are calculated reference to D.IP

```
(2021-02-08 - 2019-07-24) + 1 = 566 (days)
(2021/04/19 - 2020/04/06) + 1 = 379 (days)
```

I would like to get below tibble, but in months.

```
tibble::tribble(
      ~LastTP, ~DENDSTUDY, ~EOTVISIT, ~DEND, ~DIP,
         566L,       387L,      387L,  387L,   1L,
         379L,       386L,      386L,  386L,   1L,
         379L,       396L,      396L,  396L,   1L
        )
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, please try the below code,

### code

```r
df2 <- df %>% mutate(across(c('Last.TP','D.EndStudy','EOTvisit','D.END','D.IP'), 
~ as.numeric((as.Date(.x, '%Y-%m-%d')-as.Date(df$D.IP,'%Y-%m-%d')+1)/30.4375), 
.names = 'x{col}'))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

### output

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 10
  Last.TP    D.EndStudy EOTvisit   D.END      D.IP       xLast.TP xD.EndStudy xEOTvisit xD.END  xD.IP
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>      <chr>         <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2021-02-08 2020-08-13 2020-08-13 2020-08-13 2019-07-24     18.6        12.7      12.7   12.7 0.0329
2 2021-04-19 2021-04-26 2021-04-26 2021-04-26 2020-04-06     12.5        12.7      12.7   12.7 0.0329
3 2022-01-24 2022-02-10 2022-02-10 2022-02-10 2021-01-11     12.5        13.0      13.0   13.0 0.0329
```

Comment: Hi, I think I made a mistake when making this question.. Would you like to review this? @jkatam

Comment: sure, let me check

Comment: Your code works nicely, but it works when I fixed your code like this:
df2 <- df %>% mutate(across(c('Last.TP','D.EndStudy','EOTvisit','D.END','D.IP'), 
~ as.numeric((as.Date(.x, '%Y-%m-%d')-as.Date(D.IP,'%Y-%m-%d')+1)/30.4375), 
.names = 'x{col}'))

Comment: either ways the output is same right

Comment: Yes, your right. @

Comment: thank you, if you agree with the answer, could you please mark it as an answer

Comment: Sure, but can you help me with rounding x_Columns? Oh no. I think I figured it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251312/discussion-between-jkatam-and-d-shin).

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** OP request:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(4:8, ~ . - D.IP[1])+1,
         across(4:8, ~ as.numeric(round(./30.417, digit=1)))
         )
```

**First answer:**
We can do it using tripple `across`:

1. First we transform character class to date class.
2. Do the calculation with `across` substracting all from first row of `D.IP`
3. Again across all columns we calculate the months from days:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(across(, ymd),
         across(, ~ . - D.IP[1])+1,
         across(, ~ as.numeric(round(./30.417, digit=1)))
         )
```

```
 Last.TP D.EndStudy EOTvisit D.END  D.IP
    <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    18.6       12.7     12.7  12.7   0  
2    20.9       21.1     21.1  21.1   8.5
3    30.1       30.7     30.7  30.7  17.7
```

Comment: In real data, columns of interest is located in colnumber 4,5,6,7,8, with other columns, and It is already IDate format. can you give me more help? @TarJae

Comment: Please see my update. This should work for you.

Comment: I'm having this message..
"! Internal error: storage mode of IDate is somehow no longer integer" Do you have any idea? thank you @TarJae

Comment: Add this line: `across(3:5, ymd),` Like: `df %>% 
  mutate(across(3:5, ymd),
         across(3:5, ~ . - D.IP[1])+1,
         across(3:5, ~ as.numeric(round(./30.417, digit=1)))
         )`

Comment: This ensures that you have the correct date format. Only with the correct format you can do calculations!

Comment: one more thing... what if I would like to calculate 3:5 and 10th column to the reference? thank you!

Comment: Just like this: `c(3:5, 10)`

Comment: Hi, I think I made a mistake when making this question.. Would you like to review this? @TarJae

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `sapply` with `as.Date` to make sure it is in date format. You can use the following code:

```r
df[] <- sapply(df, \(x) {
  (as.Date(x) - as.Date("2019-07-24") + 1)/30.414
})
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Last.TP D.EndStudy EOTvisit D.END    D.IP
#>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    18.6       12.7     12.7  12.7  0.0329
#> 2    20.9       21.1     21.1  21.1  8.48  
#> 3    30.1       30.7     30.7  30.7 17.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

A different option like @TarJae mentioned in the comments (thanks!):

```r
df[] <- sapply(df, \(x) {
  (as.Date(x) - as.Date(df$D.IP[1]) + 1)/30.414
})
df
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>   Last.TP D.EndStudy EOTvisit D.END    D.IP
#>     <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1    18.6       12.7     12.7  12.7  0.0329
#> 2    20.9       21.1     21.1  21.1  8.48  
#> 3    30.1       30.7     30.7  30.7 17.7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: We could do `as.Date(df$D.IP[1])` instead of `as.Date("2019-07-24")`, then we were more flexible?!

Comment: Hi, I think I made a mistake when making this question.. Would you like to review this?